# How can we use dexie(indexedDB wrapper) in main process

Tags: dexie

Am building a electron app where am running network call in main process and database operations should be done from both main process and render process, as IndexedDB is browser based api we can access dexie directly in renderer process but main process throws exception as below:
"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MissingAPIError: indexedDB API missing".